# Delete footnote index or superscript from text using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, superscript

I need to know how to find a footnote index or superscript within a line of text and delete using google scripts.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to delete the footnote indexes in Google Document using Google Apps Script.

  - About `Delete footnote index or superscript from text using Google Apps Script`, I understood like above.
- You have the permission for reading and writing the Google Document using a script.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getFootnotes()
    .forEach(f => f.removeFromParent());
}
```

- If you want to use the standalone script type, please modify `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` to `DocumentApp.openById("###")`.

#### Note:

- **When the footnote index is deleted, the footnote is also deleted. It seems that this is the specification. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [getFootnotes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getfootnotes)
- [removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footnote#removeFromParent())

Comment: This does delete all footnotes. Thank you. What if I want to delete the second footnote of two?

Comment: @Chris Cline US - ADVS Thank you for replying. About your new question of `What if I want to delete the second footnote of two?`, in the case that you want to delete 2nd footnote, `getFootnotes()` returns an array. Using this, please modify my script to `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes()[1].removeFromParent()`. By this, the 2nd footnote is deleted. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.